# Have a problem, when I work with external_axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

I need to add to the plot some text and I tried to use your guide "How to use your own matplotlib Figure and Axes in mplfinance". But i have an error:

"ValueError: make_addplot() `ax` kwargs must all be of type `matplotlib.axis.Axes`"

My code:

```
    import mplfinance as fplt
    import pandas as pd
    
    df5M = pd.read_csv("D:\\_users_files\\Kirill\\WORK\\fx2youcom\\df5M.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    
    
    fig = fplt.figure(style='yahoo', figsize=(10.8, 6.4))
    
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
    
    sma = [fplt.make_addplot(df5M['SMA20'].tail(100), color='#f1afe1'),
           fplt.make_addplot(df5M['SMA50'].tail(100), color='#ffaf6c'),
           fplt.make_addplot(df5M['SMA200'].tail(100), color='#f0dea7')]
    
    fplt.plot(df5M.tail(100),
              type='candle',
              ax=ax1,
              style='yahoo',
              title="long_name",
              ylabel='5 Minutes',
              addplot=sma
              )
    fig
```

Comment: Is there an example of the output you expect? How do you want to add the text? Also, you specify subplots, do you want to specify 'SMA20', 'SMA50', 'SMA200', and 'candle'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you pass an external Axes object into `mplfinance.plot()` using the `ax=` kwarg, **then**

- if you want to plot volume, then you must pass an Axes object in for the volume:
   that is, instead of `volume=True` do **`volume=axes`** where `axes` is an Axes object on which you want to plot the volume.
- **you must *also* use kwarg `ax=` for all calls to `mplfinance.make_addplot()`**

This information was noted at the ***bottom*** of [**the subplots page**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/markdown/subplots.md).
Probably should also be included in [**the external axes notebook**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/external_axes.ipynb).